# boostrap carousel different sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the site working how i'd like it on my local machine, but when I view it on other computers the images in the slideshow are rending at all different sizes. It works great on my computer, but I'm having problems troubleshooting the code since I can't see the issues in my local environment. Does anyone have advice on how to troubleshoot front end issues that you can't see on your local machine? I ran the code through the W3C validator, but I feel overwhelmed but it's output. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! (sorry about all the inline stuff, I am helping a friend who's working in Dreamweaver and was asked to leave it this way.)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Full Slider - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Modernizer -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<!-- Focuspoint -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.focuspoint.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/focuspoint.css">
<!-- bx slider -->
<script src="js/plugins/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[ 

    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {

        //Fire plugin
        $('.focuspoint').focusPoint();
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
          video: true,
          useCSS: false,
          controls: true
        });
      });
    }(jQuery));


  //]]>
</script>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
    .navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
       background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       font-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li{
      margin-left:-10px;
      margin-right:-10px;

    }

    .icon-bar {
       background-color:#FFF !important;
    }

    .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: #FFC;
    }

    .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    body
    {
        background-image: url(Images/Dust_Background.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: black;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .bg
    {
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    a {
        color: #FFC;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.pull-left {
      width: 25%;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .navbar-collapse{
      border-top:0px !important;
      box-shadow:none;
    }

    body,td,th {
      font-family: "Tw Cen MT", Helvetica, "MS Reference Sans Serif";
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FFC;
    }
    a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
        body{font-size: 10px;}
    }

    @media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
        body{font-size: 14px;}
    }

    #style_text {
        text-align: justify;
        letter-spacing: .8px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    #style_text p {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .img-responsive {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
      border: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      background: transparent;
    }

    .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)
    }

    .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    }

    .bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
      background: black;
    }

  </style>

  <body>

      <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="test">
        <a href="index_vs3.html" class="pull-left"><img src="Images/kairos_logo.png" style="
      width: 250%;"></a> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="film_vs7.html">THE FILM</a></li>
          <li><a href="screenings.html">SCREENINGS</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact_vs3.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/131032179" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </li>
    <li><img src="Images/EbelKitchen.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/LightningHole.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/CharlesAlex.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Edna_JoeysRoom.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/neoncross.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="Images/overpass.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="Images/TJRosieTrainWalk.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>


  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-l">
        <div id="style_text">
          <p>
          Through a series of collective dreams an other worldly being invades the characters' dream spaces, revealing their carnivorous desires and subconscious underbellies. Relationships intertwine in unusual and fantastical landscapes as television monitors, radio frequencies, orifices and dreams all become portals to access this alternate dimension of carnality and desire.</p>
          <p>
          The characters are forced to ask what is self? What is other? What must we give up to become something else?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add height/width to the images, otherwise they'll display at their respective sizes.